# Django rest framework get data based on current userId/token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my model, i have a family table where user are able to enter their family details and store their information. But how do i get/query all the family member based on current userId ?

For eg: userId=1 added 2 family member, mother and father. How do i get these 2 family member based on the query of the current user's userId ?

here is my code :

**models**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Family(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers**

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']
    birthTime = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats, allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['userId', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'nric', 'birthday', 'birthTime']
        read_only_fields = ('userId',)
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance


class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'userId', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'relationship')
```

**views**

```
class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('=userId', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class FamilyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer


def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.request.user

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    super(CurrentFamilyView, self).perform_update(serializer)
    user = serializer.instance
    if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL and not user.is_active:
        context = {'user': user}
        to = [MyUser(user)]
        email.ActivationEmail(self.request, context).send(to)
```

Can anyone help me with get current user's family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='user_family')
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'relationship')


class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']
    birthTime = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats, allow_null=True, required=False)
    my_family = FamilySerializer(many=True, source='user_family')

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('userId', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'nric', 'birthday', 'birthTime', 'my_family')
        read_only_fields = ('userId',)
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}
```

`MyUserSerializer` now will show `userid` related family members. If you want to get current user family member you need to overwrite `get_queryset` method.

your **views.py**:

```
class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    get_queryset(self):
        return  MyUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
```

Now the view will return current user family members.

**Updates**

1. Added `related_name` in `Family` model.
2. Added `source` in `MyUserSerializer`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Ah sorry, i got an error when viewing the page due to not double checking. I have a few question, In the family serializer, do i remove userId ? And in the views.py `MyUserViewSet`, i use id instead of userId ?

Comment: For `FamilySerializer`, you can keep or remove `userId` but I don't think there is any necessity to keep `userId`. In `MyUserViewSet` use `userId` or `pk` instead of `id`.

Comment: Now i got this error `'MyUser' object has no attribute 'my_family'.` Do i have to create the 'my_family' field in MyUser model ? Sorry for all these trouble

Comment: the userId in Family models is different than the id in Family in serializer, correct ? userId = current user, id = id of family OR userId = familyId ?

Comment: Yes, the `id` in `FamilySerializer` is for `id` of `Family` model. and ` userId = current user id`.

Comment: Tested and check, it works nicely now. Thanks.
For the Family serializer, how to set the userId=self.request.user ? As it is to allow only the current user to add their own family

Comment: It would be better if you give some time to study on DRF doc. You will learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have a **user** with **id=1**

```
usr = MyUser.objects.get(id=1)
usr_famly = usr.family_set.values()
```

`usr_famly` will have all family data related to `user with id=1`