# How to get data that belongs to specific user in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets, drf-queryset

I haved Format_List model with relation with Django user and now I want to get the data belongs to specific user by giving user id or after user login.

### models.py

```
class Format_List(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'format_list'
            verbose_name = 'List of Format'
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_family')
        image_format = models.ManyToManyField(Format_Image)
        format_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.format_name
```

I am confused that how to write a API(Serializer and View) so that I can get above model data by giving specific user id in request.

I have tried this [How to retrieve all models data by User id in Django Serializer?t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073471/django-rest-framework-get-data-based-on-current-userid-token)

But in my case I want to get data assigned to each user by Admin user by giving ID in request.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What you have tried so far to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modelViewSet in views.py you can overwrite queryset for your model by:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    queryset = self.model.objects.filter(user=user)
    return queryset
```

Then you can perform CRUD operations only on this queryset